# Call 1 view in Codeigniter but share header/footer among all views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, templating

Loving Codeigniter, but I'm finding it annoying that I have to call a header, footer and the main view for each controller.

What is the best way to share a header/footer among all views and minimize replication of code. I don't want to use a template engine.

Comment: take a lookt at layout pattern [http://a32.me/2012/09/using-layout-pattern-with-codeigniter/](http://a32.me/2012/09/using-layout-pattern-with-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a view, let's call it template.php with this code

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($view);
$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```

And on your controller do this

```
//the name of the view file you want to show, in my case I want to open the login_page.php view that's inside the folder user
$data['view'] = 'user/login_page';
//load the data variable so I can use it across the views
$this->load->vars($data);
//load the template.php view that will load header, user/login_page and footer
$this->load->view('template');
```

Comment: I see no reason this should be downvoted, so I'll bump you back up to 0.

Comment: This is really clean and easy to understand so no need for downvotes +1